# Текст выходит за границы блока

Tags: html, css

Текст из <p> выходит за границы блока, выходит только длинное предложение с перечислением

> `таких брендов как Ashley Brooke, BestConnections, Black &amp; White, Converse, Event, Class International, ModernWoman, Rick Cardona, Singh S Madan, Airstep, Alba Moda, Bugatti, Buckle Up,Business Class, Codello, Comma, Eddie Bauer`

Оно печатается в 1 строку и выходит из блока, как поправить? На **max-width** не реагирует.

Comment: добавьте в задачу больше контекста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого p в css прописать `white-space: normal`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="width:200px">
таких брендов как Ashley Brooke, BestConnections, Black &amp; White, Converse, Event, Class International, ModernWoman, Rick Cardona, Singh S Madan, Airstep, Alba Moda, Bugatti, Buckle Up,Business Class, Codello, Comma, Eddie Bauer
</p>
```